# Sequential search on the same arrayList in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, sequential

```
Public Function Validate(updatedDetailList As List(Of DetailVO)) As Boolean
  Dim matchFound As Boolean = False

  For Each firstUpdatedDetail In updatedDetailList
    For Each nextUpdatedDetail In updatedDetailList
      If firstUpdatedDetail.PROD_ID.Equals(nextUpdatedDetail.PROD_ID) Then
        matchFound = True
      End If
    Next nextUpdatedDetail
  Next firstUpdatedDetail

  Return matchFound
End Function
```

I have the `updatedDetailList` as a list which I want to iterate and get the current and next object value and compare both the values. If You find same `PROD_ID` in the `updatedDetailList` then return `matchFound` as `TRUE`.

Is there any way to get next object in inner For Loop. Like...

```
For Each firstUpdatedDetail In **updatedDetailList**
  For Each nextUpdatedDetail In **updatedDetailList.Next**
    If firstUpdatedDetail.PROD_ID.Equals(nextUpdatedDetail.PROD_ID) Then
      matchFound = True
    End If
  Next nextUpdatedDetail
Next firstUpdatedDetail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to perform a distinct validation, so every item of `updatedDetailList` must be unique.

Without changing your approach (i.e using `For` loop), here is the code:

```
For i = 0 to updatedDetailList.Count - 2
  If updatedDetailList(i).PROD_ID.Equals(updatedDetailList(i+1).PROD_ID) Then
    matchFound = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

But there is a faster way to perform same - it uses LINQ:

```
Dim matchFound As Boolean = updatedDetailList.Distinct.Count <> updatedDetailList.Count
```

Comment: I was looking for this answer..                                    For i = 0 To updatedTurnDetailList.Count - 1
            For j = i + 1 To updatedTurnDetailList.Count - 1
                If updatedTurnDetailList(i).PROD_ID.Equals(updatedTurnDetailList(j).PROD_ID) Then
                    matchFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

Comment: @user1733547: then you definitely need to look into my last example (one line of code). Or create a dictionary - it would be much more readable. Creating a double loop to validate uniqueness is not a good approach, unless you are stuck in pure C. :)